# How select classes in jsoup parsing

Tags: java, android, class, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm parsing a webpage and i can parsing the id but not classes.. this is what i mean; i'm parsing the whole news wrapper id:

```
protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
                String result = "";
                // get html document structure
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                // selector query
                Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#news_wrapper");
                // check results
                if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
                    // get value
                    result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
                }

                // return
                return result;
            }
```

And it works, i can display everything but i need select only the h3 tags inside this wrapper so i tryied in this way:

```
protected String getBlogStats() throws Exception {
                String result = "";
                // get html document structure
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                // selector query
                Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#news_wrapper .news-col-1 h3");
                // check results
                if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
                    // get value
                    result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
                }

                // return
                return result;
            }
```

where `news-col-1` is a class.. but the activity is blank.. is there another way to write classes in parsing with jsoup? Thanks

Comment: you can write like this getElementsByClassName("yourclassname")

Comment: Could you share the url you are trying to parse?

Comment: http://www.multiplayer.it

Comment: @NitinMisra can you show how can i do with your suggest? i shared the url

Comment: and if i write: `Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#news_wrapper h3");` it shows only the first one and not all `h3` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to get all of the h3 tags inside that div using a class is:

```
Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3");
```

It won't work with `.news-col-1` because none of the `<h3>` tags are direct children of that div. As you commented, the id will also work:

```
Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div#news_wrapper h3");
```

The reason your code is returning only the first h3 and not all of them is because you are setting result to be only the text of the first Element in `nodeBlogStats` (when you say `get(0)`):

```
if(nodeBlogStats.size() > 0) {
    // get value
    result = nodeBlogStats.get(0).text();
}
```

Consider returning a `List` or `nodeBlogStats.text()` if you want all of the h3 text.

---

Update:

So you could change your method to return an `ArrayList`.

```
protected ArrayList<String> getBlogStats() throws Exception {
    // get html document structure
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
    // selector query
    Elements nodeBlogStats = document.select("div#news_wrapper");
    // check results
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element e : nodeBlogStats) {
        list.add(e.text());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Now i try.. do you think is difficult create a list starting from this code? can you help me please? It's exactly what i need :)

Comment: mmh what is this error? `'<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7` never seen.. it's on `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: and i think i have to create a listview in my main.xml right?

Comment: @David_D change it to `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`, and it depends how you want to display the data as to whether you need a listview. My code just shows you how to retrieve the text in an ArrayList format.

Comment: Well the best thing is have a listview that shows that data. Have you some time to spend to help me?